# Как создать сортировку записей для страницы блога WP?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно создать своего рода фильтр для сортировки и вывода записей блога.
Например по количеству просмотров статьи, по количеству лайков и дизлайков, по имени автора, по дате и тд
Возможно есть плагины для реализации подобного функционала

Comment: Разбейте задачу на части и загуглите по каждой из них решение. Это все типовые задачи, в сети полно примеров.

Comment: Обычно такого рода сортировки (фильтры) реализовываются при помощи Ajax. Естественно есть куча готовых плагинов, но не факт что вам они на 100% подойдут, можете посмотреть https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/search-filter/ для начала, затем поискать что-то похожее из платных и бесплатных решений.

Comment: @Simon спасибо большое